# Facebook SDK Single Sign On User check(compare) in Android

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, single-sign-on

I'm building Facebook Session instance using existing `Access Token`, `Permissions` and **Expiration Date** with `SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy` class (also i have the users *information* that was authorized and granted that `Access Token`. Now is it possible to somehow check whether **Single Sign On** is present and compare **native facebook** apps logged in users info (or maybe session data) with my created user info (or maybe session).

Comment: Your question doesn't show show exactly what you want. please rewrite it in a better way. Preferable with examples.